# HTML form with multiple embedded tables, a lot of white space at top of page

Tags: php, html, forms, html-table

I am having issues with a form I am trying to do in .php

I used tables, within the form, to format how I want the form to look like. The form is working correctly. But when I load the page, there is a huge white space at the top of the page, but I have no idea why it is there. I have tried looking at the source code in the web browser, and there are no html white space characters or anything out of the ordinary. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$strRequester  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
echo "<div align=center>\n";
echo "<form name='SandwichOrder' action='$strRequester' method='POST'>\n";
####Bread####
echo "<table>\n";
echo "<tr><td bgcolor='CCCCCC'><input type='radio' name='size' value='whole'><b>Whole Sandwich</b></td>\n";
echo "<td bgcolor='CCCCCC'><input type='radio' name='size' value='half'><b>Half Sandwich</b></td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr><td bgcolor='CCCCCC'><b>Choose Your Roll/Bread:</b></td><td></td></tr><br>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='bread' value='whiteroll'>White French Roll</td><br>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='bread' value='sourroll'>Sour Dough Roll</td><br>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='bread' value='wheatroll'>Wheat French Roll</td><br>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='bread' value='dutchcrunch'>Dutch Crunch</td><br>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='bread' value='nyrye'>New York Rye</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='bread' value='soursliced'>Sour Dough Bread</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='bread' value='wheatsliced'>100% Whole Wheat Bread</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
####Meat####
echo "<tr><td bgcolor='CCCCCC'><b>Choose Your Meat:</b></td><td></td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='meat' value='roastbeef'>Roast Beef</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='meat' value='turkey'>Turkey</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='meat' value='everroastchicken'>EverRoast Chicken</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='meat' value='ham'>Ham</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='meat' value='salami'>Salami</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='meat' value='pastrami'>Pastrami</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='meat' value='tune'>Tuna</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='meat' value='chickensalad'>Chicken Salad\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='meat' value='veggiepatty'>Veggie Patty</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='meat' value='vegetarian'>Vegetarian</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
####Cheese####
echo "<tr><td bgcolor='CCCCCC'><b>Choose Your Cheese:</b></td><td></td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='cheese' value='cheddar'>Cheddar Cheese</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='cheese' value='swiss'>Swiss Cheese</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='cheese' value='pepperjack'>Pepper Jack Cheese</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='cheese' value='american'>American Cheese</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='cheese' value='provolone'>Provolone Cheese</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='cheese' value='none'>No Cheese</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
####Condiments####
echo "<tr><td bgcolor='CCCCCC'><b>Choose Your Condiments:</b></td><td></td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='mayonnaise' value='mayonnaise'>Add Mayonnaise</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='mustard' value='mustard'>Add Mustard</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='lettuce' value='lettuce'>Add Lettuce</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='pickles' value='pickles'>Add Pickles</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='tomato' value='tomato'>Add Tomato</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='peppers' value='peppers'>Add Peppers</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='onion' value='onion'>Add Onion</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='olives' value='olives'>Add Olives</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='salt' value='salt'>Add Salt</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='suboil' value='suboil'>Add Sub Oil</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='pepper' value='pepper'>Add Pepper</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='avocado' value='avocado'>Add Avocado $0.50</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='sprouts' value='sprouts'>Add Sprouts $0.50</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
####Extras####
echo "<tr><td bgcolor='CCCCCC'><b>Choose Extra Meat or Cheese:</b></td><td></td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='eroastbeef' value='eroastbeef'>Extra Roast Beef $1.00</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='eturkey' value='eturkey'>Extra Turkey $1.00</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='eeverroastchicken' value='eeverroastchicken'>Extra EverRoast Chicken $1.00</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='eham' value='eham'>Extra Ham $1.00</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='esalami' value='esalami'>Extra Salami $1.00</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='epastrami' value='epastrami'>Extra Pastrami $1.00</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='etuna' value='etuna'>Extra Tuna $1.00</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='echickensalad' value='echickensalad'>Extra Chicken Salad $1.00</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='ebacon' value='ebacon'>Extra Bacon $1.00</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='eveggiepatty' value='eveggiepatty'>Extra Veggie Patty $1.00</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='evegetarian' value='evegetarian'>Extra Vegetarian $1.00</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='echeddar' value='echeddar'>Extra Cheddar $0.50</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='eamerican' value='eamerican'>Extra American $0.50</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='eswiss' value='eswiss'>Extra Swiss Cheese $0.50</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='eprovolone' value='eprovolone'>Extra Provolone Cheese $0.50</td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='epepperjack' value='epepperjack'>Extra Pepper Jack Cheese $0.50</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "</table>\n";
####Name/Instructions####
echo "<b>Add your Name or Special Instructions</b><br>\n";
echo "<input type='text' name='instructions' value='' size='50'><br>\n";
echo "<input type='SUBMIT' name='SUBMIT' value='Add to Order'><br>\n";
echo "<input type='button' name='CANCEL' value='Cancel Item'>\n";
echo "</form>";
echo "</div>\n";
?>
```

I have also tried putting the entire form into a table, but that did not help either. Any suggestions would be great. I am fairly new to .php and html and so I do not even know where to start, in trouble shooting this issue.

Comment: Did you use the Web Inspector of Firefox or Chrome to look at the white space? Also, putting everything in `echo` statements is not considered best practice.

Comment: No, is that different from using the view source?

Comment: You can look which elements have e.g., a lot of top margin and/or padding.

Comment: Ah alright, I did the inspect element with google chrome, and it is showing alot of <br> tags after the <form> tag and before any of the form elements. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: It isn't in your code, so it must be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you echoing the form into an html document? ie

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
 YOUR FORM HERE
</body>

</html>
```

(http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp)

It's likely there is default styling on your div or on the html. In your css try:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't recommend w3schools.com as a reference. It's full of errors, see http://w3fools.com.

Comment: Please read the comments, Op says: `is showing alot of <br> tags after the <form> tag and before any of the form elements.` By the way, the "simple html" of w3schools is missing a doctype, which might not be as compulsory as the `html` tag, but it's still _very_, _very_ important

Comment: @DamienPirsy Yeah I know, I wrote this before I saw his comments. And didn't notice the missing doctype, guess that pretty much proves Marcel's comment ha

Comment: what is the doctype? Is that something you have to add to the .php file for it to work correctly?

Comment: I updated my answer to include the doctype - it's a tag you put at the top of your html files to let the browser know that it's working with an html file. It doesn't have to do with php.

Comment: By the way James - is there a reason why you are echoing your html? You can include the html outside the `<?php ?>` tags and it will be sent to the browser properly.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that. I thought you had to echo everything if you have a .php page >_< that will reduce my typing by a lot.

Comment: Yeah haha. It should help with debugging too!

Comment: Well I did what you showed in your answer, and it seems to be working now. I didn't have any of the <html><head></head><body><body></html> stuff either so I added that at the same time.